# Why is my mint dying?

Tags: diseases, mint

My mint is developing brown spots on older leaves and is wilting. What disease is this? Can I save it?

[image: mint]

Comment: The white spots give me a feeling that there may be spider mites around sucking out the chlorophyll out of the leaves. Can you check for them under the leaves and share if you can spot any spider mites?

Comment: Yeah, I checked and found some small mites under the leaves.

Answer (score 1):

Spider Mites are likely the reason for the white spots and ultimate issues on your mint. They spread really quickly to all other nearby plants so be sure to isolate your plant, check other plants as well. Spider Mites thrive in hot, dry conditions, so if you can increase humidity and spray water on/under your plants that could help a lot. Dealing with Spider Mites does feel like a tough battle, but if you rinse them consistently and increase the overall humidity, you can nurse your plants back to health.